# Date validation in Java - take two

Tags: java, object-oriented, datetime, validation, reinventing-the-wheel

I read through and implemented the advice I received [**yesterday**](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/85579/date-validation-in-java/85596?noredirect=1#comment154284_85596).

I would, once again, really like some input on how this can be improved. 
e.g. encapsulation, interfaces, abstract classes etc..

Right now, it's one class.

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

class DateValidator {

    private static DateValidator dateValidator;
    private static DateFormats dateFormats;

    static {
        dateValidator = new DateValidator();
    }

    private enum DateFormats {
        DDMMYYYY, MMDDYYYY, YYYYMMDD;

        private static final Map<String, Integer> setupDateFormat(DateFormats dateFormats, String date) {

                Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

                String value = date.replaceAll("[^0-9]","");

                switch (dateFormats) {
                    case DDMMYYYY: {
                        try {
                            map.put("day", Integer.parseInt(value.substring(0, 2)));
                            map.put("month", Integer.parseInt(value.substring(2, 4)));
                            map.put("year", Integer.parseInt(value.substring(4, 8)));
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            System.out.print(e);
                        }
                        break;
                    }

                    case MMDDYYYY: {
                        try {
                            map.put("month", Integer.parseInt(value.substring(0, 2)));
                            map.put("day", Integer.parseInt(value.substring(2, 4)));
                            map.put("year", Integer.parseInt(value.substring(4, 8)));
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            System.out.print(e);
                        }
                        break;
                    }

                    case YYYYMMDD: {
                        try {
                            map.put("year", Integer.parseInt(value.substring(0, 4)));
                            map.put("month", Integer.parseInt(value.substring(4, 6)));
                            map.put("day", Integer.parseInt(value.substring(6, 8)));
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            System.out.print(e);
                        }
                        break;
                    }

                    default:
                        System.out.println("Wrong date-format...\n Choose either DDMMYYY / MMDDYYYY / YYYYMMDD");

                }

                return map;
            }

    }

    private enum Months {
        JANUARY(1, 31), FEBRUARY(2, 28), MARCH(3, 31), APRIL(4, 30), MAY(5, 31), JUNE(6, 30), 
        JULY(7, 31), AUGUST(8, 31), SEPTEMBER(9, 30), OCTOBER(10, 31), NOVEMBER(11, 30), DECEMBER(12, 31);

        private final int monthNumber;
        private final int numberOfDaysInMonth;

        private static final Map<Integer, Integer> map;

        private Months(int monthNumber, int numberOfDaysInMonth) {
            this.monthNumber = monthNumber;
            this.numberOfDaysInMonth = numberOfDaysInMonth;
        }

        static {
            map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

            for (Months m : Months.values()) {
                map.put(m.monthNumber, m.numberOfDaysInMonth);
            }
        }

        private static Map<Integer, Integer> getMap() {
            return map;
        }

    }   

    public static final DateValidator setDDMMYYYY() {
        dateFormats = DateFormats.DDMMYYYY;
        return dateValidator;
    }

    public static final DateValidator setMMDDYYYY() {
        dateFormats = DateFormats.MMDDYYYY;
        return dateValidator;
    }

    public static final DateValidator setYYYYMMDD() {
        dateFormats = DateFormats.YYYYMMDD;
        return dateValidator;
    }

    //EMPTY NON-CALLABLE CONSTRUCTOR
    private DateValidator() {}

    private static boolean isLeapYear(int y) {
        return (y % 4 == 0) && ((y % 100 != 0) || (y % 400 == 0));  }

    public static boolean checkDay(String date) {
        try {
            Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

            map = DateFormats.setupDateFormat(dateFormats, date);
            int day = map.get("day");
            int month = map.get("month");
            int year = map.get("year");

            int daysInMonth = (month == 2 && isLeapYear(year)) ? 29 : Months.getMap().get(month);
            return day <= daysInMonth && day >= 1;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.print("You need to call setDDMMYYYY(), setMMDDYYYY(), setYYYYMMDD() FIRST\n");
            return false;
        }
    }   
}

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print(DateValidator.setDDMMYYYY().checkDay("16101990"));
    }
}
```

Comment: You should really not return static fields. Currently you give back a singleton `dateValidator`. However, the functioning of that validator changes when you call another `set` method. That means that different parts of code can influence each other. Try and stay away from `static` fields, and if you do need them, keep them immutable. Calling something `setXxx` and then returning a value is not a good naming convention. Call it `retrieveX` or `getInstance` instead.

Comment: In `Map<String, Integer> map` the variable `map` is a reference. In your code you first create an empty map and assign it to `map` upon creation (within `checkDay`). Immediately afterwards you assign it a new map, throwing away the previous reference, meaning that the empty map will have to be garbage-collected. You should of course not create the empty map for nothing. Again naming: `map` is not a descriptive name, and I would not expect a method called `setupDataFormat` to return a map.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes That looks like good feedback - why don't you post it in an answer rather than as two long comments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the most terrible part:

```
} catch (Exception e) {
     System.out.print(e);
}
```

Just let it be. Do you expect an exception? If so, avoid it. Otherwise, let it be. One day a bigger program of your starts malfunctioning, after some while you'll find that it prints `null` or some other ¨useful" messages to the console and after many days you may find where and maybe even why.

`e.printStackTrace` would be waaaaay better, but it's still a non-sense. Exception exist in order to *be propagated to a place where they can be handled*. I mean "handled", not "swallowed".

---

A similar stuff:

```
default:
    System.out.println("Wrong date-format...\n Choose either DDMMYYY / MMDDYYYY / YYYYMMDD");
```

It's an enum, and there is no other value. Some companies (e.g. Google) have a rule that a `default` clause must be always present. I can't really follow it as I prefer a compiler warning concerning the missing case. Anyway, a default clause printing something is wrong for about the same reason as above. Will the program work? No way. So throw an exception.

---

The usage should look like

```
DateValidator.DDMMYYYY.validate("16101990");
```

Make `DateValidator` to an `enum`, remove the setters, create no objects in this call as you don't need them.

---

I'd start like this (the comments are just for this CR):

```
public enum DateValidator {
    DDMMYYYY(4, 2, 0),
    MMDDYYYY(4, 0, 2),
    YYYYMMDD(0, 4, 6),
    ;

    private DateValidator(int yearIndex, int monthIndex, int dayIndex) {
        ...
    }

    public boolean validate(String date) {
        // throwing an NPE on null input is usually best
        // currently, all formats have length 8
        // (this may change later, but no need to care now)
        if (date.length != 8) return false;
        // http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/CharMatcher.html
        if (!MATCHER.matchesAllOf(date)) return false;
        // This can't throw as everything has been checked.
        int year = Integer.parseInt(date.substring(yearIndex, yearIndex+4));
        ...
    }

    private static final CharMatcher MATCHER = CharMatcher.range('0', '9');

    private final int yearIndex;
    private final int monthIndex;
    private final int dayIndex;
}
```