# Implementing a date validator using enum

Tags: java, datetime, reinventing-the-wheel, enum

[**First**](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/85579/date-validation-in-java?noredirect=1#comment154463_85579) and [**second**](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/85672/date-validation-in-java-take-two/85708#85708) post on the same subject. This is such a great way to learn.

Once again I'm open to suggestions. I have implemented almost all of the suggestions from before, which have resulted in the code looking like this:

```
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


enum DateValidator {
    DDMMYYYY(0, 2, 4),
    MMDDYYYY(2, 0, 4),
    YYYYMMDD(6, 4, 0);

    private final int dayIndex;
    private final int monthIndex;
    private final int yearIndex;

    private DateValidator(int dayIndex, int monthIndex, int yearIndex) {
        this.dayIndex = dayIndex;
        this.monthIndex = monthIndex;
        this.yearIndex = yearIndex;
    }

    private int getDay(String date){ return Integer.parseInt(date.substring(dayIndex, dayIndex + 2)); }
    private int getMonth(String date){ return Integer.parseInt(date.substring(monthIndex, monthIndex + 2)); }
    private int getYear(String date){ return Integer.parseInt(date.substring(yearIndex, yearIndex + 4)); }

    private static boolean isLeapYear(int y) {
        return (y % 4 == 0) && ((y % 100 != 0) || (y % 400 == 0));  }

    private boolean isDateLegal(String date) {
        final int day = getDay(date);
        final int month = getMonth(date);
        final int year = getYear(date);
        boolean isValid = false;

        final Set<Integer> values = new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12));
        final int daysInFebruary = (month == 2 && isLeapYear(year)) ? 29 : 28;

        if (day > 0) {
            if (values.contains(month)) { isValid = day <= 31; } 
            else if (month > 0 && month < 13 && month != 2) { isValid = day <= 30; }
            else if (month == 2) isValid = day <= daysInFebruary;
        }

        return isValid;
    }

    private static boolean isDateFormatValid(String date) {

        final String DATE_PATTERN = "(^" + "[0-9]{2}\\.[0-9]{2}\\.[1-2][0-9]{3}|" +
                                     "[0-9]{2}\\-[0-9]{2}\\-[1-2][0-9]{3}|" + 
                                     "[0-9]{2}\\/[0-9]{2}\\/[1-2][0-9]{3}|" +
                                     "[0-9]{2}\\s[0-9]{2}\\s[1-2][0-9]{3}|" +
                                     "[0-9]{2}[0-9]{2}[1-2][0-9]{3}|" +
                                     "[1-2][0-9]{3}\\.[0-9]{2}\\.[0-9]{2}|" +
                                     "[1-2][0-9]{3}\\-[0-9]{2}\\-[0-9]{2}|" +
                                     "[1-2][0-9]{3}\\/[0-9]{2}\\/[0-9]{2}" + 
                                     "[1-2][0-9]{3}\\s[0-9]{2}\\s[0-9]{2}" +
                                     "[1-2][0-9]{3}[0-9]{2}[0-9]{2}" +")$";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(DATE_PATTERN);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(date);

        return matcher.matches();
    } 

    public boolean validate(String date) {
        return this.isDateLegal(date.replaceAll("[\\.\\-\\/\\s]", "")) && isDateFormatValid(date);
    }
}

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print(DateValidator.DDMMYYYY.validate("16.10.1990") ? "Date is valid" : "Date is NOT valid");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Handling exceptions

`Integer.parseInt` throws a `NumberFormatException` when there is a parsing error, you may want to consider catching that and then just output the validation status as `"Invalid"`.

## Field names

```
final Set<Integer> values = new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12));
```

These aren't just any `values`, these represent months with 31 days in them. :) Probably call this as `monthsWith31Days`? I also understand you want to make it clear that these months are obviously unique in the collection (in layman terms), but considering this is only used internally within the method, I don't think there's much harm leaving it as just a `List`.

## Day validation logic

Personally, I will start from the most constrained case and work my way down. The slight advantage is that your 'wider' cases will not need to check that is it *not* any of the constrained cases (e.g. look at how you do a `month != 2` for the first `else if` branch). In conclusion, this means you can validate for the month of February first, then the 31-day validation, and finally for all remaining months. You can also `return` immediately from each of the branch, instead of one `return` statement at the end.

## Putting it altogether for `DateValidator.isDateLegal()`

```
    private boolean isDateLegal(final String date) {
        final int day = getDay(date);
        final int month = getMonth(date);
        final int year = getYear(date);
        final List<Integer> monthsWith31Days = Arrays.asList(1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12);
        if (day > 0) {
            if (month == 2) {
                // BTW no need to check if month = 2 here
                return day <= isLeapYear(year) ? 29 : 28;
            } else if (monthsWith31Days.contains(month)) {
                return day <= 31;
            } else if (month > 0 && month < 13) {
                return day <= 30;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

---

## Regex

Now onto the big one... your regular expression is ideal for simplification by applying the following rules:

- `[1-2]` can be represented as `[12]`.
- Metacharacters (e.g. `.`) are interpreted literally in character classes, so there is no need to escape them.
- To match `-` inside a character class, put it at the last so that it doesn't get interpreted as a range syntax.
- Just as you have used a character class to do your separator replacement for `date`, you should do likewise for your `DATE_PATTERN` too.
- In addition to the previous point, you can then apply capture groups to check that the same separator is used.

## Putting it altogether for regex

```
private static boolean isDateFormatValid(final String date) {
    final String DATE_PATTERN = "^([0-9]{2}([./\\s-]?)[0-9]{2}([./\\s-]?)[12][0-9]{3}|" 
            + "[12][0-9]{3}([./\\s-]?)[0-9]{2}([./\\s-]?)[0-9]{2})$";
    final Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(DATE_PATTERN).matcher(date);
    return matcher.matches() && (Objects.equals(matcher.group(2), matcher.group(3))) 
            && (Objects.equals(matcher.group(4), matcher.group(5)));
}
```

(BTW, `Objects.equals()` is a Java 7 method and it is a simple null-safe implementation of calling the first argument's `equals()` with the second argument. This is important as `matcher.group()` can return `null` for non-matches.)

Pro-tip: Actually, you may want to go a step further by grouping the day and year values, and make sure that the length of both parts (i.e. `DD,YYYY` or `YYYY,DD`) are different:

```
private static boolean isDateFormatOk(final String date) {
    final String DATE_PATTERN = "^([0-9]{2}|[12][0-9]{3})([./\\s-]?)[0-9]{2}([./\\s-]?)" 
            + "([0-9]{2}|[12][0-9]{3})$";
    final Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(DATE_PATTERN).matcher(date);
    return matcher.matches() && (matcher.group(1).length() != matcher.group(4).length())
            && (Objects.equals(matcher.group(2), matcher.group(3)));
}
```

*(Pro-pro-tip: The `Pattern` can be a `private static final` field...)*

For the `validate()` method, you can check for a valid format first before validating the entire string:

```
public boolean validate(final String date) {
    return isDateFormatValid(date) && isDateLegal(date.replaceAll("[./\\s-]", ""));
}
```